# How to get value from `core_config_data` table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

Magento 1.x use `Mage::getStoreConfig('sections/groups/fields')` get data on `core_config_data` table.

How to Magento2 get value from `core_config_data` table ?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

We need to call the default method available.

Just use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`,
in your constructor argument and set the class property: `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;`

Now to get the configuration value just use

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/template_hints', 
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

I have get the answer from [this link](http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2015/06/get-system-config-values-in-magento-2.html) and refer [this](https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/building-magento-2-extension-extendedconfig/)

Comment: good one Meenakshi! keep it up

Comment: How do you obtain them from a separate script, not from within the magento filesystem or a module?
If you make a class in your script and instantiate it, what should the class inherit from, and how do you ensure it loads all the proper files?

Comment: Which scope does this get the configuration from? The currently viewed storeview by the customer?

Comment: yes, it'll take current storeview of the customer

Comment: how to use the same using object manager?

Comment: How i can get value Without cache

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR How to set the scope i mean store view for selected admin user using module https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/322871/57334

Answer (score 4):

Create a function for getting configuration values in your custom module's helper.

```
public function getConfig($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
}
```

and call anywhere you want for example in test.phtml

```
$moduleStatus = $this->helper('Customvendorname\Custommodulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

In block and helper call like this:

```
 $this->_objectManager->create('Customvendorname\Custommodulename\Helper\Data')->getConfig('sectionid/groupid/fieldid');
```

Comment: It's recommended in M2 to prefer the DI approch. Thus, using `$this->_objectManager->create(...)` should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @AnnaVölkl, then what is the replacement of that please can you post a similar answer here ?

Comment: See the upvoted answer above.

Comment: please tell me how to find out path/of/config. I am trying to find the configuration value for the enabled section of Payment method

Comment: @CodeForGood this is defined in your module >>etc >>system.xml. For any system configuration setting, field is defined in the following manner 
'section' >> group >> field' so your path will be ''sectionid/groupid/fieldid'

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following method to retrieve the variables,

```
if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
    $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        'design/header/welcome',
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}

return $this->_data['welcome'];
```

Comment: please tell me how to find out path/of/config. I am trying to find the configuration value for the enabled section of Payment method

Comment: You can get the information from system.xml file

Answer (score 1):

First you need to include the `Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface` class in your constructor:

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your class' method you can call the following:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/of/config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: please tell me how to find out path/of/config. I am trying to find the configuration value for the enabled section of  Payment method.

Comment: you got this from core_config_data table

Comment: @CodeForGood this is defined in your module >>etc >>system.xml. For any system configuration setting, field is defined in the following manner 'section' >> group >> field' so your path will be ''sectionid/groupid/fieldid

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your class already has a `Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context` injected. You can get a `ScopeConfig` from there:

```php
$this->context->getScopeConfig()->getValue(
    'sections/groups/fields',
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
);
```

Comment: please tell me how to find out path/of/config. I am trying to find the configuration value for the enabled section of Payment method

Answer (score 0):

**In template (phtml) files, I use in the following way:**

```
$config = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form::class);
$configValue = $config->getConfigValue('web/secure/base_url');
```