# Magento 2 > Get 'free shipping' minimum order value

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, configuration, free-shipping

In **Magento 2.1.x** Lets say I want to show the minimum order amount for free shipping in a block somewhere in my website, how can I retrieve this value?

The setting has been configured in `Stores > Configuration > Sales > Shipping Methods > Free Shipping > **Minimum Order Amount**`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to retrieve the good config path and use this method : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78473/33619

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 */
private $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

/**
 * @return float
 */
public function getFreeShippingSubtotal()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
}
```

> We need to call the default method available.
>
> Just Use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
>   $scopeConfig, In your constructor argument and set the class property:
>   $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
>
> Now to Get the configuration value just use
>   $this->scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/template_hints',
>   \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);