# Get value from "core_config_data"

Tags: magento2, core-config-data, magento2.2

I'm trying to get value from the `core_config_data` table but when I follow various guides on the internet or previous topics here, it doesn't work..

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to PHP and Magento in general so I'm not completely sure what I'm doing..

The class is:

```
class Db
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getApiKey()
    {
        $getApiKey = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('vendor_module/general/ApiKey',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $getApiKey;
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate the class by calling `$new = Db(); $new->getApiKey;` it returns the below error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function vendor\module\src\Model\Db::__construct(), 0 passed in /xxxxx/src/Model/Db.php on line 23 and exactly 1 expected in /xxxxx/src/Model/Db.php on line 9
```

I have tried to re-run `setup:di:compile`
cleared cache folders, removed contents of `magento/generated` (I don't have `var/generation` in magento 2.2.0..) and still nothing.

Links I'm aware of: [How to get value from `core_config_data` table in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78457/how-to-get-value-from-core-config-data-table-in-magento-2)

https://maxyek.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/building-magento-2-extension-extendedconfig/

http://magehelper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/get-system-config-values-in-magento-2.html

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a Db object directly, which doesn't make use of Magento's Dependency Injection (DI) functions, you should either:

1. [Use DI to inject](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) your Db object directly in the `__constructor()` of the class you are using it in:

   ```
   public function __construct(\Path\To\Your\Class\Db $db)
   {
       // now your Db class is instantiated with the 
       // ScopeConfigInterface as expected
       $this->db = $db;
       // use as you will
       $this->db->getApiKey();
   }
   ```

or

2. Create it with a "[Factory](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)" class (if you need more than one instance)

   ```
   public function __construct(\Path\To\Your\Class\DbFactory $dbFactory)
   {
       // this "virtual" class dbFactory let's you create Db objects, 
       // populated with your DI objects like ScopeConfigInterface
       $this->dbFactory = $dbFactory;
       // here's how to create a Db object from the Factory
       $db = $this->dbFactory->create();
       // use as you will
       $db->getApiKey();
   }
   ```

Comment: option 1 worked, thanks. I wasn't quite sure if I could DI into a plugin, but after some tests it came out I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your script does not works because of missing argument in constructor, when you call `$new = Db();` you should pass the instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` inside it, like:

```
$new = Db($scopeConfig);
```

Where the `$scopeConfig` instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

You can find an info about "How to run external script in Magento 2" [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script)

Comment: Thanks, I've used the solution provided by thaddeusmt, which worked.