# cant override a addtocart.phtml file in custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-view

How to replace a  custom  text (from backend) for add to cart button and stock availability  in product view page in  my custom module magento 2

[image]

**Updated**

> app\code\Cm\Preorder\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Type\Simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="Cm_Preorder::product/view/type/default.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cm_Preorder::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cm_Preorder::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Cm\Preorder\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Pre order'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cm_Preorder" setup_version="1.0.1" schema_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>   
    </module>
</config>
```

any help me to solve this

Comment: Any Solutions for that?

Comment: @Kanhaiya lal answer was  working

Comment: My problem i can't override the `addtocart.phtml` file in my custom module so can you advise me?

Comment: wait i will my code

Comment: above code is working perfectly in my custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom module add  a file 
for example : `app/code/[NAME_SPACE]/[MODULE]/i18n/en_US.csv`

in this file

```
"Add to Cart","New word for add to cart"
"In Stock","New word for in stock"
```

Then clear the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Note** if still not came then in your custom module check the sequence of the module and then add **Magento_Catalog** as dependent module  then do setup upgrade.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy // (-f add if you are in developer mode)
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

### As per updated question fetch add to cart text from admin

create a helper `app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
namespace NAMESPACE\MODULE\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface 
     */ 
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig

    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getAddToCartText()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/store_information/add_to_cart', // update as per your backend need 
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

for add to cart text get from admin override the file in your theme `app/design/frontend/NAMESPACE/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
$customHelper = $this->helper(NAMESPACE\MODULE\Helper\Data::class);

<?php $buttonTitle = __($customHelper->getAddToCartText()); ?>
```

same process for in-stock, same helper add new function and call in respective area.

---

### [Override a template inside a custom module instead of theme](https://github.com/kanhaiya5590/M2-template-override-in-custom-module-instead-of-theme)

Example of overriding `addtocart.phtml` for **simple product**

so in custom module create a file `app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <page  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
            <body>
                <referenceBlock  name="product.info.addtocart">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">NAMESPACE_MODULE::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>

               <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">NAMESPACE_MODULE::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </body>
        </page>
```

`product.info.addtocart` is used for simple products, and `product.info.addtocart.additional` is used for configurable products.

then copy the `addtocart.phtml` file vendor to `app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml` and do some necessary change (as per current requirement add a custom helper and update the button text).

Note  : it is mandatory to add module sequence (`<module name="Magento_Catalog"/>`)  is `module.xml` file.

**hope you will get your expected output.**

Comment: No i need to change a  custom text from backend

Comment: @divyasekar i guess you are looking for https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/78473/52244 (how to get store config data in store front)

Comment: No, i already get a config value in frontend. my need is  how to replace in frontend  in product view page

Comment: I m confused with   whether i need to override a product view page  or customize a  stock availablity and add to cart button in frontend

Comment: @divyasekar Need to override the template example for add to cart `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml` to in your theme and via helper you can replace the button text and same step need to do for In stock

Comment: @divyasekar i updated my answer as per need in question like fetch data from admin so i create a `helper code` and `call in addtocart.phtml`, please refer the code. more help will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any chances to override a addtocart.phtml  file in custom module  from custom template

Comment: @divyasekar see the update answer

Comment: its not override

Comment: @divyasekar,1. just want to know which type of product are you working,2. if simple then this code will work, 3. can you please update the code of module.xml file so i can see the sequence, and also update the path of catalog_product_view.xml path of your module in question and also the path of template phtml

Comment: i want to both configurable and simple product

Comment: i will post my code wait

Comment: Please check a edit question

Comment: @divyasekar see the updated xml code

Comment: not yet nothing happens

Comment: @divyasekar i created a custom module to override a template file in custom module instead of theme. https://github.com/kanhaiya5590/M2-template-override-in-custom-module-instead-of-theme and same i tested for simple and configurable product. if this work you will get output test instead of addtocart button so need to update content for vendor and update as per your need, please don't forgot th share the updated feedback

Comment: now only i noted.  layout file not called in my module

Comment: I dont know hoe to slove this

Comment: In my xml file i willl mention a wrong path but  not showing a error its will run fine but i m giving a wrong  block  but it runs fine my xml file not called

Comment: @divyasekar might be the magento mode is not set to developer mode so you not get direct error, try to check log or change the mode to developer mode via `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`, can you confirm shared custom module working

Comment: when i create a normal custom block it will appear https://prnt.sc/nmtq2u but  i used a above xml layout is not working

Comment: normal custom block were created https://prnt.sc/nmts6t   it will appear prnt.sc/nmtq2u  but  i was try to addtocart it was not called

Comment: @divyasekar add some dummy text in addtocart.phtml file at the top and see, might be some condition not allow to execute the code.

Comment: ok i will test it and update you

Answer (score 2):

> **Add To Cart Button Text Change :-**

**Override This File In Your Module :-**

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

```
<div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
```

You Can get Your Config Value Using **ScopeConfigInterface** And
Change `$buttonTitle` with your Value.

> **"In STOCK" Text Change :-**

**Override This File :-
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml**

```
    <div class="stock available" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: No i need to change a text from backend

Comment: using backend like to create configration for chnge text ??

Comment: i was already create a configuration in backend   and i had doubt in how to bring a custom text in  frontend

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Its looks fine to add to cart  text replacement and i need  stock availabity also

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Cannot override a addtocart.phtml file in custom module https://prnt.sc/nmpvdi

Comment: Please see a code in above question

Comment: addtocart file not override ???

Comment: can you please help solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274562/in-magento-2-how-to-override-stock-availability-in-product-detail-page-in-custom)