# How can I get the a selected option of Admin->configuration->Sales->Deliver Methods->flatrate-> field id? I need to inject this into a class

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, configuration, filter

I will be injecting this into a ViewModel or Plugin.
I have a custom configurable field in the Admin->configuration->Sales->Deliver Methods->flatrate and I need to check the value of it to compare with another string because it will change over time.

Example:

```
if ($this->flatrateConfigCustomOptionValue === $value) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the shipping method configuration value then you need to use the following code for Magento AbstractCarrier, as your Shipping method must be extending this class.

**Magento Core has the following methods in  Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier**

```
/**
 * Retrieve information from carrier configuration
 *
 * @param   string $field
 * @return  false|string
 */
public function getConfigData($field)
{
    if (empty($this->_code)) {
        return false;
    }
    $path = 'carriers/' . $this->_code . '/' . $field;

    return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        $path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $this->getStore()
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieve config flag for store by field
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @return bool
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
 */
public function getConfigFlag($field)
{
    if (empty($this->_code)) {
        return false;
    }
    $path = 'carriers/' . $this->_code . '/' . $field;

    return $this->_scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
        $path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        $this->getStore()
    );
}
```

Assume your field id is {fieldid}
then you can use the following method to get the configuration value on your FLATRATE shipping method class

```
/** 
 * get shipping method configuration on Flatrate Carrier Model
 **/
    $fieldidvalue=$this->getConfigData('{fieldid}');
```

and then you can add comparison with you static variable : flatrateConfigCustomOptionValue

```
if ($this->flatrateConfigCustomOptionValue === $fieldidvalue) {}
```

Method for Outside Shipping Method Model :
If you want to get configuration from outside of Shipping Model then you need to use the following method for that

step 1. add  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig in you constructor

step 2. Provide member variable access

step 3 : create a function to get configuration

Step 4: Get specific field id value from configuration and compare as per required

```
/**
 *@param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
  ....... Other parameters................
 **/
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ....... Other parameters................
) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    ....... Other parameters................
    }

public function getConfigData($field)
{
    $storeID=GET/ADD YOUR STORE ID HERE;
        $path = 'carriers/{youshippingmethodcode}/' . $field;
        //{youshippingmethodcode} replace with your shipping method code
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeID
        );
}

then again use same way to get the value and do comparison
/** 
* get shipping method configuration on Flatrate Carrier Model
**/
$fieldidvalue=$this->getConfigData('{fieldid}');

and then you can add comparison with you static variable : flatrateConfigCustomOptionValue 
if ($this->flatrateConfigCustomOptionValue === $fieldidvalue) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi all the admin configuration are store in core_config_data. You can get the store config data using scopeconfig.
[How to get value from `core_config_data` table in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78457/how-to-get-value-from-core-config-data-table-in-magento-2)